# Wordpress session gets lost in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, session, firefox

I am working with wordpress template. I used my template page for crud functionality.  It's working well but one page is creating problem of session. It looses the session in mozilla firefox. If I refresh that page or redirect to another page then the session automatically gets lost..  Can somebody help me wid a solution.. and why on earth is this happening??

P.S: That particular page is working perfectly in chrome,safari and IE i.e it doesnt loose the session.

Thanks!

Comment: Can You give us a link to that page? And check wheter some links are linking to `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` if there are links with and without `www` this can be the cause

Comment: in that myprofile-> edit page

Comment: I'm using FireFox 18 and everything is alright. Maybe browser is not a couse? Check it again it works for me.

Comment: ohh is it??  then why is that the other versions are throwing the problem?? any idea??

Comment: Think I know the problem. Your link is: `http://www.helpmecure.in/edit?id=someID`, try to change it for `http://www.helpmecure.in/edit/?id=someID` with `/` before `?`

Comment: thanx bumerang.. i found my solution with the below answer that has been given..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the issue because of the Mozilla's Cache Management

Actually the thing is that wp create meta tag for next and prev. link and to make your performance batter Mozilla Preload Next post which might be the issue you are facing try below code that might help you to resolve the issue

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
```

Add the above line in your functions.php file and this might solve your issue